# How to get Kovan testnet faucet

Tags: ethereum, solidity, kovan

How to get kovan faucet i tried some ways but failed so how can get some kovan faucet so is there any way to get these free testnet

Or how  to test the flash loan for free in testnet

Answer (score 0):

Kovan is a deprecated testnet so getting kETH is not possible anymore (couldn't find a faucet that's still working).

If I were you I would switch to Goerli. Alchemy has a faucet: https://goerlifaucet.com/ (account required)